# Optimizing select count(*) from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table **Eli** with 1 million records. When I query the following:

```
Select count(*) from Eli where userId ='my_user'
```

It is taking more than 10 mins to give results. I searched web and found better way to optimize the query from `http://dbatipster.blogspot.com/2009/08/get-row-counts-fast.html`.

How do I utilize the the following query into my above query-

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.id) [Table_Name], i.rowcnt [Row_Count] 
FROM sys.sysindexes i WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE i.indid in (0,1) 
ORDER BY i.rowcnt desc
```

Comment: Have you created an index for `userID`?

Comment: 1 million rows is not a large number, even when there's no covering index it shouldn't run for ten minutes to do a full table scan. Bte, the 2nd Select can only be utilized for the row count without any WHERE-condition.

Answer (score 1):

Without touching on properly building a table, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(userID) FROM Eli (NOLOCK)
WHERE userId ='my_user'
```

The `(NOLOCK)` hint allows you to select from the table without other transactions against the Eli table being committed, meaning you're not waiting for other updates and inserts to complete before returning your results.

Comment: Sorry, -1 and may you be fired. NOLOCK may lead to WRONG RESULTS being reported - as rows may be included multiple times. It is pretty much ONLY appropriate on read only tables due to this.

Comment: @TomTom The question was specifically, how can the that optimized query be adapted to their query to return results quicker. Part of that optimized query was the `NOLOCK` hint, providing information about what it does. They can decide whether that works for what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vwEli
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT userId, cnt = COUNT(*)
    FROM Eli
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.vwEli (userId)
GO

SELECT cnt
FROM dbo.vwEli --WITH(NOEXPAND)
WHERE userId = 'my_user'
```

Answer (score -1):

The easy fix to see improvement would be add an index on the table on the userID, if you intend to use the userID filter very often in your queries. Of course that if userID is the primary key of your table, the index would not be necessary and maybe other ways to improve needs to be checked.
Now, the query you have provided should be applied as this to make it easier for you:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(i.id) [Table_Name], i.rowcnt [Row_Count] 
FROM sys.sysindexes i WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE i.indid in (0,1) 
AND OBJECT_NAME(i.id) = 'Eli';
```

The original query you posted listed the row counts for all objects in the database in descending order of the number of rows.

Answer (score -2):

> It is taking more than 10 mins to give results

A cound over 1 million rows does not take that long. You bark the wrong tree. Totally. On a comical level - like complaining about the fuel consumption of a car with a broken tank leaking fuel. Seriously.

The only reason you would ever take that long is excessively bad locking - which is what you should fix. 1 million rows is nothing. Even on a 10 year old computer on a slow hard disc from that era it would not take even a minute to do your query. Something is blocking here. Likely other code written by a not competent programmer that is keeping around locks for way longer than it needs, possibly even excessive locks.